# Pass values from one table to another

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 tables (table 1 and table 2) both tables contain a string field name "theName".
And I also have 2 forms (form 1 and form2) form 1's record source is table 1 and form 2's record source is table 2. I want to enter a value for "theName" on form 1 then click a button which opens form 2 to a new record and then sets "theName" field to the value entered on form 1. So for example if I entered the value "John" in the "theName" field on form 1 and then clicked a button which would open form 2 to a new record and then set the "theName" field to "John". I have some code to start but it won't work for me.

Is it possible to open and form to a new record and then set a fields value automatically?

```
Dim theName As String
theName = Me.theName

DoCmd.openForm "form2", , , "theName=" & Me.theName
```

Comment: Your database is not in 3rd normal form if you are storing the same data in two places. I suggest you think about creating a third table with just names and an AutoNumber as primary key as well as a third form that accepts just names. By doing this you eliminate redundant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a value to a control in the second form immediately after you open the form.

```vb
' open form2 in add mode
DoCmd.OpenForm "form2", DataMode:=acFormAdd
' assign value to text box named theName
Forms!form2!theName = Me.theName
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply , where do i put "Forms!form2!theName = Me.theName" ? i put it in the filter box on form 2 but it didn't work, form 2 just opens to blank form and the "theName" is not set

Comment: I thought you were calling `DoCmd.OpenForm` from VBA code on form1, so my intention was to include `Forms!form2!theName = Me.theName` on the next line in that procedure code.

Comment: Great that works thanks.  just one more question how can i make it sure no duplicates are entered into the table . so for example if "john" is entered once it can not be entered again

Comment: What i am looking to is use an if statement to check the the name entered already exists, so for example : IF theName exists open form2 to the variable name theName Else if theName does not exist open form2 to a new record and set theName to the value enterd for theName on form1 .

Comment: Use `DCount` as your `If` condition.  If the count of a name is zero, use the approach from my answer to add a record for that name.  Otherwise, when the name exists in the table, use the *WhereCondition* option with `DoCmd.OpenForm` to open the form filtered to that name.

Comment: Ok i'll try that and get back to you if i have any trouble thanks for your help

Comment: Got it sorted thanks for your and help and pointing me in the right direction. Dim theName As String
theName = Me.Name

Dim countRecordsInTable As Long
countRecordsInTable = DCount("theName", "Table 2", "theName = '" & theUnitname & "' ")

If countRecordsInTable = 0 Then
MsgBox ("no records found" & " " & countRecordsInTable)
DoCmd.openForm "form2", DataMode:=acFormAdd
Forms!form2!theName = Me.theName


ElseIf countRecordsInTable > 0 Then
MsgBox (countRecordsInTable & " record(s) already exists")
DoCmd.openForm "formOV", , , "unitName = '" & theUnitname & "'"